# How to order my jQuery output properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By using jQuery selectors and fetching the text (.text()) my output is very messy because of the messy set of the html selectors. To I receive data like this:

```
DATA1
                      DATA2
       DATA3
                              DATA4
```

And need to make it look like this:

```
DATA1
DATA2
DATA3
DATA4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. Here click the `<>` button and create a [mcve]

Comment: Did you try to `trim()` the result of `text()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the result string using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method and trim out the whitespace using [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) or [`jQuery.trim`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method.

```js
var str = `DATA1
                      DATA2
       DATA3
                              DATA4`;

console.log(
  str.split('\n').map(function(v) {
    return v.trim();
  }).join('\n')
)

// or using jQuery.trim

console.log(
  str.split('\n').map(jQuery.trim).join('\n')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = yourElemenet.text().trim().replace(/\s+/g, '\n');
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.